# How to get input values of multiple form in a single page using vanilla js?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a div that contains multiple form element. How do I get the input values of the exact form that user has submitted by pressing **ENTER Key**? Assume that user can append more forms in the container. So i need to get the exact form values that user has submitted by pressing Enter.

Here is the markup:

```
<div class="forms-container">
    <form class="form">
        <input type="text" name="firstName">
        <input type="text" name="lastName">
    </form>
    <form class="form">
        <input type="text" name="age">
        <input type="number" name="phone">
    </form>
    <form class="form">
        <input type="text" name="address">
        <input type="text" name="address2">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: If you're pressing enter to submit, it would submit the form to the form's "action" attribute, which defaults to the same page. Are you using a back-end language? The form/post variable there should only include inputs from the submitted form.

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

1. You should have only one form wrapping all inputs, and it should
   have a unique ID.
2. Any HTML elements without a closing tag must
   have an ending slash.
3. You need some kind of button to accept input. There's many ways to
   run a function on the button click; below is one way.

```js
document.getElementById("submitButton").addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    processForm()
})

function processForm() {
    var formData = Object.fromEntries(new FormData(document.querySelector('#myForm')).entries())
    console.log("Form data is: ", formData)
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm" class="form">
    <input type="text" name="firstName" />
    <input type="text" name="lastName" />
    <input type="text" name="age" />
    <input type="number" name="phone" />
    <input type="text" name="address" />
    <input type="text" name="address2" />
    <input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: * Hi there, Firstly thanks a lot for the answer, earlier I couldn't find handling multiple return values from form within a dialog box.

* Also, I would have to disagree w point no. 2 as self closing tags do not need a trailing `/` in HTML.


Here's the reference [from mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Void_element#self-closing_tags)